# android unity game optimisation

Tags: unity, rendering, optimization, gpu

I'm finishing my game,
i'm in the stage of optimisation, i tried multithreaded rendering and dynamic batching, with OpenGLES3.. 
i get a little bit increase , but now i'm getting function Clear take too much GPU ms..
any help guys

[image]

Comment: What shaders do you use?

Comment: the build in Mobile.difuse

Comment: Try clearing only the depth by setting the clear flag in your camera. Then the GPU won't waste time erasing the pixel buffer, which will get overwritten anyway. Except if you are not filling every single pixel every frame, then that wouldn't work.

Comment: Thx lasse ill try it when i get home , but actually how do i check if im filling every single pixel every frame or not ? (I think i'm btw )

Comment: @Lasse that didn't work